# How can I pass a route action as a parameter to an Index method with MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have the following route where any URL that starts with A, F or L is directed
to the Index action. It looks like a C sharp regular expression is used.

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "content",
            "{page}/{title}",
            new { controller = "Server", action = "Index" },
            new { page = @"^[AFL][0-9A-Z]{3}$" }
        );
```

I would like to do something similar but this time direct any URL that has an action of Menus, Objectives, Pages or Topics to go to the Index action and pass the words "Menus", "Objectives", "Pages" or "Topics" to the Index action as a parameter:

Can someone show me how I can do this. It looks like a C# kind of regular expression bubut I am not sure how to do the expression I need for the second
route.

Comment: *It looks like a C sharp regular expression*. This tells me that you didn't look at the docs before ask...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a simple route constraint :

```
   context.MapRoute(
        "content",
        "{page}/{title}",
        new { controller = "Server", action = "Index" },
        new { page = @"Menus|Objectives|Pages|Topics" }
    );
```

And then your action method signature will look like this :

```
public ActionResult Index(string page)
{
    ...
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example here...

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs
you have define a route with a parameter.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Content",
    "Content/{TypeOfAction}",
    new {controller="Content", action="Index"},
    new {@"\b(Menus|Objectives|Pages|Topics)\b"}

);
```

Asuming you have a ContentController with an Index action which handles TypeOfAction as parameter

Edited the answer:
`\b` in a Regex finds word boundaries... have not tested it but should work...
http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html
http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Comment: But the route you gave will allow anything in the TypeOfAction. What I need is for only those in the question.

Comment: Edited the answer... syntax is out of my head so you might have to tweak it a little... /b finds word boundaries via Regex